# Share folder in VirtualBox Host=Mac OS, Guest=Debian

Tags: virtualbox

how can I share a folder in VirtualBox between my host-OS Mac OS and my installed guest-OS Debian 6? I installed the guest additions and created a shared folder, but I cannot find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Debian but in Ubuntu I had to do the following after setting it up in the VB GUI:

```
mkdir /home/username/OSX # one time
sudo mount -t vboxsf OSX /home/username/OSX # each time
```

Comment: This is all covered in the VirtualBox help file, FWIW... relevant section in the online version: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual

Comment: Tried that and got: /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error